# PostgreSQL: Check if any item from array exists in the db property, which is array too

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Looking for a way to check if one of the items of given array exists in db property, which is also an array.
I have a table *'Events'*, which has a property *weekDays*, which is an array of numbers *[1,2,3,4,5]*.
Given an array *searchDays* which is [2,3], I want to check if the one of the items exists in *weekDays*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you need to look for overlap. The operator is `&&`

```
SELECT * FROM Events where weekDays && ARRAY[2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

[you are looking for intersecion I suppose:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
t=# with c(weekdays,searchdays) as (values(array[1,2,3,4,5],array[2,3]))
select weekdays && searchdays from c;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```